# Can't find solution to codingbat array challenge

Tags: java, arrays

I have been working on codingbat problems for java and have come across a problem in array-2 which I cannot solve using only one loop. The problem is as follows :

Given a non-empty array of ints, return a new array containing the elements from the original array that come before the first 4 in the original array. The original array will contain at least one 4. Note that it is valid in java to create an array of length 0.

I looked at other solutions but they all use two loops, and the Array-2 problem set should be done using only one loop. I am not sure how to approach this, here is my solution with two loops :

```
  public int[] pre4(int[] nums) {
  int[] notnums = new int[0];
  for(int i = 0; i<nums.length;i++)
    if(nums[i]==4){
      notnums = new int[i];
      for(int j = 0;j<i;j++)
        notnums[j] = nums[j];
        return notnums;
    }
  return notnums;

}
```

Comment: The whole point of a challenge is to force you to think about solutions to these problems on your own.  Similarly, the whole point of Stack Overflow is questions and answers, not "gimme teh codez".

Comment: @JoeC Well ofcourse I don't want you to code it for me, I'm just wondering how to approach the problem as I can't seem to think of any way to solve it

Comment: But here's the thing.  Writing the code always has been, and always will be, the easy part.  The hard part is always breaking down the problem into a sequence of steps.  That is the point of the challenge, and having us do it for you defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: @JoeC Well I understand that, but I'm not sure how to move forward from here as I can't seem to come up with a solution. If I can't solve it myself, I don't see a problem in asking others for their opinion so next time I face a similar challenge, I will know how to tackle it.

Comment: This is not the site to ask these kinds of questions.  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site, and which are not.

Comment: @JoeC It says you should ask about specific programming problems and I have presented exactly that

Comment: See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @JoeC Thanks for clarifying, I seem to have misunderstood the purpose of this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a coding challenge, I won't answer with code, instead, here's how you should approach it:

- Declare another array
- Start iterating first array, element by element
- If the element is 4, break out of loop
- If the element is not 4, add it into another array

In the end, second array should have all the elements that are present before first 4.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

my solution for 1 loop:

```
public int[] pre4(int[] nums) {
    int[] res = new int[0];
    for(int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if (nums[i] == 4) 
        res = new int[i];
      else 
        if (res.length > 0)
          res[i] = nums[i];
    }
    return res;
  }
```